# How to detect BLE RSSI values?

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to develop an app capable of detecting BLE signals and show its RSSI value (apart from other parameters). From now I am capable of detecting BLE and list it in a `ListView` but I am stuck on how to pass the parameter RSSI when it has been detected to the `BaseAdapter` that I have developed for the `ListView`.

This is the code I used to detect the BLE device:

```
// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
    new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            addDevice(device);
        }
    };
```

Here it is the addDevice code that is implemented in another class where it is the code above:

```
protected synchronized void addDevice(final BluetoothDevice device) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

And final, here it is the `BaseAdapter` I use for the `ListView`:

```
public class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private List<BluetoothDevice> data;
private Activity context;



public LeDeviceListAdapter(Activity context, List<BluetoothDevice> data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

public synchronized void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    if(!data.contains(device) ){
    data.add(device);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (null == convertView) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.leaf_devices_list_item, null);
        convertView.setTag(new DeviceView(convertView));
    }
    DeviceView view = (DeviceView) convertView.getTag();
    view.init((BluetoothDevice) getItem(position), null);
    return convertView;
}

public class DeviceView {


    private TextView title;
    private TextView status;
    private TextView type;
    private TextView address;
    private TextView rssivalue;

    public DeviceView(View view) {
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
        status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_status_txt);
        type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_type_txt);
        address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address_txt);
        rssivalue = (TextView) view.findViewById(id.signal_intensity_txt);
    }

    public void init(BluetoothDevice device, Intent intent) {
        title.setText(device.getName());
        address.setText(device.getAddress());
        setType(device.getType());
        setStatus(device.getBondState());
    }
}
```

The "rssivalue" is the `TextView` I am going to use to show the RSSI.

I have taken parts of the codes from each class that I thought it was relevant for this. If it is needed I will provide the code that are important for this case.Please, somebody help me to solve this problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the rssi value from `LeScanCallback`:

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
    new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
             yourBleAdapter.addDevice(device, rssi);
        }
    };
```

In your adapter, this becomes:

```
public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi) {
       //get device and its rssi locally here
    }
```

thats where you get the rssi value from.  It is from the sample code that i use. Works.

Comment: I tried that but I don´t know how to implement it in the Adapter so I can show it. What part of the code should I modify in order to get the have it? In addDevice, I have to change the arguments to:(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi)??

Comment: deleted a comment from above which had github project links -now a 404